# quickblox one to one chat not connecting to chat service

Tags: quickblox

I am trying to use quickblox one to one chat but it doesnt connect to chat server it says err:connection :reset..i am trying to figure out what is wrong ..i am using javascript sample of quickblox even the demo is not working